# Antlr4.StringTemplate.dll locked by another process

Tags: dll, jenkins, robocopy

I have a DLL named Antlr4.StringTemplate.dll. When I try to robocopy this file from one server to another from Jenkins CI, I keep getting the following error:

```
Waiting 30 seconds... Retrying...
    Newer             296448    Antlr4.StringTemplate.dll
2015/01/01 20:32:13 ERROR 32 (0x00000020) Copying File C:\Users\Administrator\.jenkins\workspace\BuildCode\src\CodeScheduler\bin\release\Antlr4.StringTemplate.dll
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

I tried using ProcessExplorer to find out the process locking the file. Found that it was w3wp.exe. I stopped "World Wide Web Publishing Service" and now the ProcessExplorer doesn't show any process using the file. But I still keep getting the above error while robocopy. Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: That's weird, I met a similar problem and solved the same way like you did.

Answer (score 0):

I did this from 'groovy console' on the Jenkins node though.

```
println "taskkill /f /im example.exe".execute().text
println "tasklist".execute().text
```